# How to send '-X POST' using 'requests' library in Python?

Tags: python, post

I am trying to replicate shell command:

```
curl -u [staff_email]:[api_key] -F "case[attachments][0]=@/path/to/file1.ext" -F "case[attachments][1]=@/path/to/file2.ext" -F "case[content]=I need help" -F "case[subject]=I need help" -F "case[user_email]=user@domain.ru" -F "case[user_full_name]=FullName" -F "case[language_id]=2" -F "case[custom_fields][cf_44]=3" -X POST https://[domain].omnidesk.ru/api/cases.json
```

into Python code using Requests library:

```
import requests
```

What is a proper syntax for this example (curl -X POST)?

Comment: The same in English

Comment: Please only post in *English*, otherwise just use https://ru.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#http-verbs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `requests.post`, as explained [here](https://realpython.com/python-requests/#other-http-methods)

for the attachments part (your first `-F`), read [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files)

for the auth part (-`u`): [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/?highlight=basicauth#basic-authentication)